# Why is my golang program having this error. exec: "lib/synonyms": file does not exist

Tags: go

Im new to programing and im trying to learn golang. I am writing practice programs and this one is called domainfinder which is made of subprograms, one of them being synonyms. I made a build.bat file that pipes all the programs together and puts them in a lib folder. the domainfinder main.go then executes all the programs and runs them together here is a piece of main.go in the domainfinder folder.Im sorry if the question isnt great Ive never asked a question on here before.

```
package main
import(
  "log"
  "os"
  "os/exec"
)
var cmdChain = []*exec.Cmd{
  exec.Command("lib/synonyms"),
  exec.Command("lib/sprinkle"),
  exec.Command("lib/coolify"),
  exec.Command("lib/domainify"),
  exec.Command("lib/available"),
}
```

Comment: All this program does is call external programs. Did you write the other programs?

Comment: You're using relative paths. Are those files under the lib/ directory, which is under the current directory?

Comment: yes all of the sub programs are already written and work. the lib folder is inside the domainfinder folder. domainfinder/lib/synonyms. and the main.go that runs all the programs is in domainfinder next to the lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec.Command("lib/synonyms")` means to execute the file `lib/synonyms` *relative to the directory the program was run from*, not relative to the `main.go` source.

If your project looks like this:

```
domainfinder/
  main.go
  lib/
    synonyms
    sprinkle
    coolify
    domainify
    available
```

The program will only work when executed from the `domainfinder/` source directory. Anywhere else and it will not be able to find the files. Or worse, it will execute some unrelated files with the same name.

Instead you have to make sure these executables get shipped along with your executable (I'm not going to demonstrate that because it's not a good idea). Then use [os.Executable()](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable) to find where your executable is stored and get the files relative to that.

```
package main
import(
  "os/exec"
  "log"
  "os"
  "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
  ex, err := os.Executable()
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  executableDir := filepath.Dir(ex)
  libDir := filepath.Join(executableDir, "lib")

  cmd := exec.Command(filepath.Join(libDir, "synonyms"))
  stdout, err := cmd.Output()
  log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
  log.Printf(string(stdout))
}
```

However, instead of calling executables it's far, far better to instead write them as Go libraries and functions. This will result in more robust, simpler, and easier to use code. If you must have additional executables, write them as libraries and provide a thin executable wrapper.

[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) covers how to structure a Go project.

Comment: Thank you. Im going to read up on the documentation you linked to.